# Methods to ruggedise a USB3.0 type A port

Tags: usb, communication, usb-host, industrial, peripheral

I am developing a carrier board for a autonomous navigation robot. I need to change the USB 3.0 type A ports to ensure a reliable connection in a rough terrain.

I am familiar with some methods as:

1. [USB Screw-locks plug](https://www.newnex.com/usb-3-locking-cables.php) and [receptacle](https://www.amphenol-icc.com/product-series/rugged-usb-3-0.html?__cf_chl_jschl_tk__=2ca1bbb7cf17023b22ebdc0e71c8ec8d0e37d3ed-1596248265-0-AY7gGoly4RCFtkvbN7s9OH8krkQ3D-5nkO2wa-FlT_sKbd8Bz7hTIHrKQRSvcA-608IP4QAb52FaNsdXgv7UQr2CszdIwgjSRkLCAt-3i4gKRHmdyUYLv_iDsb0UfyWJR33Sv5qbCD8M2IZdYsXK3tLgbHBYFcT-WF2ynOGok4CLHOairWHTqSp_T3MYy6OgmqiqEEtL22k9tCviBVNyv0X2p-UrsKRsDsDQ-4cVWmfH4TgWtr9lA4vIbatcsa6Z9EVMMMP84hKM3F8dJGxql_X8K_fvyaP03Ek9jsV_9yuS27BajP748TTmBJig_pQi0J147DBOuCtAejSQkX1fuuk1F6qB9yIDw8uuTH3GBg5CjxLLvu39V9pmRR5GX7Hmfg)
2. [Hercules Connectors](http://steeredtechnology.com/downloads/MERITEC-HERCULES-USB-TYPE-C-MIL-DTL-38999-ISO.pdf)
3. [Lockable USB receptacle](https://www.amphenol-icc.com/product-series/lockable-usb-connector.html)
4. [Bulgin Buccaneer Sealed USB Data Connectors](https://in.rsdelivers.com/product/bulgin/px0842-a/bulgin-buccaneer-single-port-straight-panel-mount/4686311)

What other options do I have ?

[Source 1](https://www.connectorsupplier.com/usb-connector-products/)

Comment: What USB speed are you using? Are you using superspeed channels?

Comment: @Jon We are using a maximum of 250MB/s.